# Show that a 1 dimensional subspace of a CG-module is a submodule.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Good evening,

I am trying to finish the following proof from an old exercise sheet I have from my third year of university a few years ago.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb CG$-module.

Suppose that $V$ is simple of degree $>1$ and $x\in V$. Prove that $\sum_{g\in G}gx=0$.

Thanks to @Nitrogen for pointing me in the right direction, I am trying to prove that $\mathbb C\cdot(\sum_{g\in G}gx)$ is a 1-dimensional submodule of $V$. Then since V is simple, this submodule must be ${0}$, thus the statement follows. However, I can't seem to finish it off. I have pasted what I have so far below, and if anyone would be willing to take the time to take a look, that would be great.

Let $U$ Be the subset of $V$ with basis $ \{ \sum_{g\in G}g\cdot x \}$

All elements $ u\in U $ are of the form

$$
 \lambda ( \sum_{g\in G}g\cdot x) \lambda\in \mathbb{C}
$$

So it's a subspace since for $ u = \lambda ( \sum_{g\in G}g\cdot x)$,  $ u' = \lambda' ( \sum_{g\in G}g\cdot x) $ and $  \mu \in \mathbb C $ we have

$ 0 \in U$ since $0=0\cdot ( \sum_{g\in G}g\cdot x)$ and $0\in \mathbb C$

$ u+u' \in U $ since $  \lambda + \lambda' \in \mathbb C$

$  \mu u \in U$ since $\mu \lambda \in \mathbb C $.

To show its a sub module,

We must show that $ \forall g\in G  $ and $u\in U$ we have $g\cdot u\in U$.

Let $u\in U$ be defined as before and take $h\in G$

$$
h\cdot u = h \cdot ( \lambda\sum_{g\in G}g\cdot x)
$$

How do I proceed from here?

Thank you in advance.

Andy.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be focusing on the wrong things here. Look:
$$
h\sum_{g\in G}g=\sum_{g\in G}hg=\sum_{g\in G}g
$$
Now, if $x\in V$ is such that $v=\sum_gg.x=\left(\sum_gg\right).x\neq 0$, then $v$ spans a 1-dimensional submodule because
\begin{align*}
h.v&=h.\left(\sum_g g.x\right)\\&=\sum_gh.(g.x)\\&=\sum_g(hg).x\\&=\left(\sum_g hg\right).x\\&=\left(\sum_gg\right).x=\sum_gg.x=v.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks again, David! So since v spans a 1-dimensional submodule, this submodule must be {0}, which contradicts the assumption that v is not equal to 0, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Out of curiosity, would my argument in the question also work if I used the last part of your answer to show that it was a submodule, that must be {0}. Therefore the sum in the question must be equal to 0?

Comment: Yes, I just thought you were putting too much effort into checking you has a (vector) subspace. The linear span of a bunch of elements is clearly a subspace.

Comment: Ah okay. I guess I was trying to be too thorough! Also, why is the sum of gh equal to the sum of g as g runs through G? I always thought that that would just be the sum of elements of a (right) coset of a group, which weren't necessarily all elements of the group? Forgive me if that's a stupid question, it's been a while since I delved into the world of abstract algebra!

Comment: The map $g\mapsto gh$ is a bijection $G\to G$, so multiplying $\sum_gg$ by $h$ just permutes the terms in the sum.